# Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file' : AngularJS SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, single-page-application

I'm very new to Angular SPA and for the first time I get a code by Googling and try to run. But I get some errors in Console. I couldn't figure out why, I found list of following Console errors:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/Users/hp/Downloads/single-page-app-angularjs-master/home.html.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
>
> Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load
>   'file:///C:/Users/hp/Downloads/single-page-app-angularjs-master/home.html'.
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   file:///C:/Users/hp/Downloads/single-page-app-angularjs-master/about.html.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
>
> Error: [$compile:tpload]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.3/$compile/tpload?p0=home.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Single page web app using Angularjs</title>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.3/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="single-page-app">
  <div ng-controller="cfgController">
  <div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation" style="padding-left:130px;">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#/">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#/about">About us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#/about">Read tutorial</a></li>
      </ul>
</nav>
</div>
  <br/>

  <div ng-view class="jumbotron"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems you are running into a CORS issue: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: Typically, Ajax isn't supported when using `file://`. You'll want to serve and access the page through an HTTP server. Note: [http static server one-liners](https://gist.github.com/willurd/5720255)

Comment: I think this problem has so many solutions I was using to make ajax calls. I didn't understand the error at first but this is nothing but I have not turned on my ---->>>> network.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Windows:

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

or

```
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security
```

On Mac:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Comment: Where I have to type this on windows ?

Comment: I tried by running the commands on command prompt.Its giving this error--'chrome.exe' is not recognozed

Answer (score 1):

i faced something Like that and resolved by using application server like `Glassfish` ...

in other words using `http://` protocol instead of `file://`