# Calling JIRA REST Api from Javascript in local HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jira-rest-api

I´m trying to call JIRA REST Api from javascript in HTML running locally by using jQuery.ajax function like below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://jira.myhost.com/rest/api/2/issue/AB-123",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: false,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        var base64 = "YWRtaW46YWRtaW4";
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
    }
})
.fail(function (error) {
    console.log(error.statusText)
});
```

When opening HTML file in Chrome I get following error in console:

```
NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://jira.myhost.com/rest/api/2/issue/AB-123'.
```

However, I can successfully access the same JIRA REST Api by using CURL locally:

```
curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://jira.myhost.com/rest/api/2/issue/AB-123"
```

Any tip on how to get this working from JavaScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922881/error-failed-to-execute-send-on-xmlhttprequest-failed-to-load-file-ang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Andreas!

**Solution**

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ --args --disable-web-security
```

**Note**, this is just a temporary solution on CORS issues locally on my machine and is only used for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

What helped for us was removing the User-Agent header in our Apache proxy before forwarding the request to JIRA

```
<Location "/rest">
    RequestHeader unset User-Agent
</Location>
```

This also requires mod_headers enabled in Apache.