# Calling Jira REST api in javascript failed

Tags: javascript, jira-rest-api

I am testing out a single-page application to integrate with Jira's data.

Below is the code:

```js
async function getJiraIssue(issueId) {        
    try {
        let uri = 'https://my.jira.server/rest/api/latest/search?jql=id='+issueId;
        let response = await fetch(uri, {
            headers: {'Authorization': `Bearer MYJIRAPERSONALACCESSTOKEN`},
            redirect: 'error'
        });
        let data = await response.json();
        return data;
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject(err);
    }
}
```

When testing in Chrome and debugging with the Developer's Tool, the `fetch` line got a red curvy underline tailed by an error sign whose hovered-over text said `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED`. The `err` caught said `TypeError: Failed to fetch at ...`. The `...` part is just the stack with my code as the top frame. The same request works with `curl`, e.g., `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer MYJIRAPERSONALACCESSTOKEN" https://my.jira.server/rest/api/latest/search?jql=id=PROJ1-123`. I was reading [Calling JIRA REST Api from Javascript in local HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586685/calling-jira-rest-api-from-javascript-in-local-html-file), but not sure if it is the same issue.

Is this related to Jira API authentication? What is missing or done incorrectly?

Comment: You should include the entire error. I'd assume a CORS issue.