# Difficulty with SQL Server 2014 training kit

Tags: sql-server, google-chrome

Trying to work on this training kit to get educated with SQL Server 2014.
As seen here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=41700

I can't get it to work. It seems to come with a pdf explaining how to get it to work on your browser. Apparently by default the browser (chrome) won't run "application that use XML configuration files when they are run from a local computer" The only way to get it to work is by placing "--allow-file-access-from-files" to the google chrome shortcut properties window in the "target" location.

Even after doing all this I still get a message saying "network error" and the message on the top of the screen on the browser saying "To run this page in google chrome, close Chrome then create a shortcut with the --allow-file-access-from-files" property on..." (basically telling me to do the thing I just did following pdf instructions the kit came with)

Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By 'can't get it to work' do you mean you can't download it?

Comment: This is a link to Download SQL Server 2014 Developer Training Kit Sample Databases from Official Microsoft Download Center, is that right? Perhaps you have past in the wrong link?

Comment: Can't get it to work means once I click the html file to start the kit. It opens up a a webpage on my browser. The problem is I cannot click on anything on the browser and a error message/banner shows at the top of the browser screen explaining me to create a shortcut of the browser with "--allow-file-access-from-files" property on. Despite following the instructions, it still gives me the error message.

Comment: So your problem has more to do with Chrome than SQL Server? Can you download other types of files? DO any other Microsoft downloads work? Do you have any other browsers you can try? It certainly works in my chrome. I have version `48.0.2564.116 m`

Comment: It could be something to do with the xml file that can't be accessed by chrome browser. The thing is it gives me instructions to handle this but it is not wokring. The exact message that comes up is "NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHTTPRequest': failed to load file///C:/SQL%202014%20Dev%20Training%20Kit/SQLData.xml' "

Comment: The real question is why does it function for everyone except you? Are you on a locked down OS or something? These three links all say the same thing:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922881/error-failed-to-execute-send-on-xmlhttprequest-failed-to-load-file-ang, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23997449/allure-report-nothing-shown-in-chrome, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487803/why-does-this-filesystem-api-requestquota-call-fail

Comment: From one of the links I see there is an entry "chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security". I will try that once I get back home from work. The "--disable-web-security" part might be the issue.

Comment: Yeah placing in the --disable-web-security part did not work. I have ran out of all options. Seems like other people with my problem fix it...does my operating system have anything to do with it. The security options maybe not allowing browser to access any files on my computer?